# Logic Pro X Automation from Midi file cannot be undone

Tags: logic-pro, automation

so I imported some old Midi files into Logic and the volume/panning automation was still intact, however I couldn't override or disable it.

I hit the 'show automation' button and select 'write' on each track. Then I set the levels to 0 and hit play and the old panning/automation is still occurring in the background completely ignoring the new settings.

Is this an issue with the midi file? Or am I missing something?

If this is still unclear, I could make a quick screen cast showing the exact steps i'm taking.

Comment: Perhaps there MIDI automation within the MIDI Region, have you checked this?

Comment: Have you considered asking this on the appropriate forum, namely the Apple Logic forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a MIDI file, any pan/voleme information in it would be in the forum of MIDI Control Change messages.  In many hosts that's a different thing from the kind of host-side track automation curves/channels that it sounds like you're looking at.
Check the Event List  in Logic. (or whatever equivalent it has now)
http://www.logic-users-group.com/forums/showthread.php?t=5815